# mysql query does not execute

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, scripting

I am trying to run some queries from bash. first, how can I connect once and perform SELECT queries from different dbs? and the following code does not work.

```
> $LOG_FILE
> $SQL_FILE

for sam in $db
do
  echo "USE ${sam}; SELECT login, FORMAT(SUM(PROFIT), 2) AS PROFIT FROM MT4_TRADES WHERE CLOSE_TIME >= '2016-12-01'  AND CLOSE_TIME < '2016-02-29' AND CMD IN (0 , 1) GROUP BY LOGIN LIMIT 10;" >> ${SQL_FILE}
done

while read line

do

  echo "beginning: `date "+%F %T"`" | tee -a ${LOG_FILE}

  out=`echo "$line" | mysql -N --host=${Host} --user=${User} --password=${Passwd} 2>&1`
  echo "$out" >> ${LOG_FILE}

  if [[ ${?} -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "RESULTS FETCHED: `date "+%F %T"`" | tee -a ${LOG_FILE}
else
        echo "FETCHING RESULT failed" | tee -a ${LOG_FILE}
        exit 1
fi


done < ${SQL_FILE}
```

Comment: What is your error output and do you have a line number/location in your script where the failure occurs?

Comment: how can I show the error output?

Comment: You have a number of `echo` statements.  How many of these succeed?  You can also probably be more exact, but this would be a start.